# LEFT OUTER JOIN with OR versus UNION

Tags: mysql, sql

Are there significant performance considerations between using UNION versus LEFT OUTER JOIN with OR in the WHERE clause?

What is the difference between these two queries?

Is it often better to use LEFT OUTER JOINs instead of a UNION?

My reason for asking is I actually need to do an INSERT, and can't use a UNION even if I wanted to.

```
SELECT t.foo
FROM t
INNER JOIN t1 t1.t_id=t.id
WHERE t1.id IN (1,2,3)
UNION
SELECT t.foo
FROM t
INNER JOIN t2 t2.t_id=t.id
INNER JOIN t2a ON t2a.t2_id=t2.id
WHERE t2a.id IN (1,2,3)
UNION
SELECT t.foo
FROM t
INNER JOIN t3 t3.t_id=t.id
INNER JOIN t3a ON t3a.t3_id=t3.id
WHERE t3a.id IN (1,2,3);

SELECT DISTINCT t.foo
FROM t
LEFT OUTER JOIN t1 t1.t_id=t.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 t2.t_id=t.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2a ON t2a.t2_id=t2.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN t3 t3.t_id=t.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN t3a ON t3a.t3_id=t3.id
WHERE t1.id IN (1,2,3) OR t2a.id IN (1,2,3) OR t3a.id IN (1,2,3);

UPDATE t
LEFT OUTER JOIN t1 t1.t_id=t.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 t2.t_id=t.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2a ON t2a.t2_id=t2.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN t3 t3.t_id=t.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN t3a ON t3a.t3_id=t3.id
SET t.foo="bar"
WHERE t1.id IN (1,2,3) OR t2a.id IN (1,2,3) OR t3a.id IN (1,2,3);
```

Comment: Why can't you use union? Check the explain plan of both queries, run them and you will be able to see which one performs better

Comment: @sagi  How would you use one with an UPDATE?  And regardless, still would like to better understand the implications of these two approaches.

Comment: @sagi  Or do I just put the UNION in the WHERE clause?

Comment: Just like @GordonLinoff solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with many performance questions, you should test the results on your data and your systems.  The `union` and `left join`s are doing very different things -- and which is better probably depends on features of your data, available indexes, and other considerations.

However, you *can* use the `union` method in `update`.  You just need a subquery:

```
update t join
       (select t.id, t1.foo . . .
        union . . . 
        select t.id, t2.foo
       ) tt
       on t.id = tt.id
    set t.foo = 'foo'
    where . . .;
```

You might also find it more efficient to use the `union` approach but to break the update into multiple separate `update` statements.

Comment: What do you mean by `You might also find it more efficient to use the union approach but to break the update into multiple separate update statements.`?

Comment: He means that instead of using union, update once with the first select, and the with the second (two different update statements or more)

Comment: So, use three separate queries?

Comment: @user1032531 . . . One query for each subquery in the `union`.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use `UNION` in inserts.

```
INSERT INTO `table`
SELECT * FROM   
(
    SELECT '1'
    UNION
    SELECT '2'
) x
```

Same goes for updates:

```
UPDATE `table1` t1
JOIN (
    SELECT '1' as col1
    UNION
    SELECT '2'
) x ON x.col1 = t1.colX  
SET t1.whateverColumn = "someValue"
```

As for performance, it's mainly down to indexes. Both can be fast, both can be slow. If you're indexing them correctly, you shouldn't see big differences between the two.